# C# Reflection - merge two objects together

Tags: c#

I have a need to update object A's property if null with that from object B's equivalent property if that is not null. I wanted code I can use for various objects.

I had a version working until one of the objects contained a propert of type List, which is where I have a blank in the code below. My main question is how can I best implement this part of the code. Secondly is there a better way of doing this whole thing and thirdly I know its never going to be rapid but any suggestions to speed it up would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
public T MergeWith<T, U>(T primarySource, U secondarySource) where U : class, T
    {
        Type primaryType = typeof(T);
        Type secondaryType = typeof(U);
        foreach (PropertyInfo primaryInfo in primaryType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (primaryInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                object currentPrimary = primaryInfo.GetValue(primarySource, null);

                PropertyInfo secondaryInfo = secondaryType.GetProperty(primaryInfo.Name);
                object currentSecondary = secondaryInfo.GetValue(secondarySource, null);

                if (currentPrimary == null && currentSecondary != null)
                {
                    primaryInfo.SetValue(primarySource, currentSecondary, null);
                }
                else if ((currentPrimary != null && currentSecondary != null) && isChildClass(primaryInfo))
                {
                    if (isCollection(currentPrimary))
                    {
                        // here


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MethodInfo method = typeof(NavigationModel).GetMethod("MergeWith");
                        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(primaryInfo.PropertyType, primaryInfo.PropertyType);
                        object returnChild = generic.Invoke(this, new object[2] { currentPrimary, currentSecondary });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return primarySource;
    }

    private bool isCollection(object property) 
    {
        return typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(property.GetType())
            || typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.GetType()); 
    }


    private bool isChildClass(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        return (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass && !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
                            !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName != "System.String");
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem, i recentlly created an extention method that does something very similar and it works fine with collections so long as the property is writable.

Answer (score 7):

I have created the below extension method for use in my latest project and it works fine, collections and all.  It is a pretty much a simpler version of what you are doing in your method.  With mine both classes have to be the same type.  What problem do you encounter with collections?

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static TEntity CopyTo<TEntity>(this TEntity OriginalEntity, TEntity NewEntity)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] oProperties = OriginalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo CurrentProperty in oProperties.Where(p => p.CanWrite))
            {
                if (CurrentProperty.GetValue(NewEntity, null) != null)
                {
                    CurrentProperty.SetValue(OriginalEntity, CurrentProperty.GetValue(NewEntity, null), null);
                }
            }

            return OriginalEntity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like his solution copies data from one type to another type.  You'd need to extend your answer to take type type arguments, and define how you determine which properties are equivalent between types.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, i understand what my code does, however the differences you point out do not relat to the stated problem, i.e. how do i deal with collections. It is an example of something that works fine with collections and more to the point demonstrates the fact that properties that are collections should not need to be treated differently to other types of properties.

Comment: I need to loop through each object in the list performing another recursive call if both not null, to again set its proprties. If the the item is in the list of the second object (but not primary object) then add it. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I modified Ben Robinsons solution in order to not overwrite Collections or list, instead, it adds the elements of one object to the other one where the merging is happening:

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TEntity CopyTo<TEntity>(this TEntity OriginalEntity, TEntity EntityToMergeOn)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] oProperties = OriginalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo CurrentProperty in oProperties.Where(p => p.CanWrite))
        {
            var originalValue = CurrentProperty.GetValue(EntityToMergeOn);

            if (originalValue != null)
            {
                IListLogic<TEntity>(OriginalEntity, CurrentProperty, originalValue);
            }
            else
            {
                var value = CurrentProperty.GetValue(OriginalEntity, null);
                CurrentProperty.SetValue(EntityToMergeOn, value, null);
            }
        }

        return OriginalEntity;
    }

    private static void IListLogic<TEntity>(TEntity OriginalEntity, PropertyInfo CurrentProperty, object originalValue)
    {
        if (originalValue is IList)
        {
            var tempList = (originalValue as IList);
            var existingList = CurrentProperty.GetValue(OriginalEntity) as IList;

            foreach (var item in tempList)
            {
                existingList.Add(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```