# Is there a better way to do this? (Compare/Merge specific properties on two objects)

Tags: c#

Here is the situation

```
public class A {
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
}

A a = new A(){ Prop1="A", Prop2 = 1}
A b = new A(){ Prop1="B"}

//Merge Two objects into a but only specific properties
a.Prop1 = a.Prop1 != b.Prop1 ? b.Prop1 : a.Prop1; //This part.

//a = {Prop1: "B", Prop2: 1}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Right now I've got 20 properties and I'm just copy/pasting this line with small changes over and over again. In Javascript with jQuery this would just by `$.extend(a, b)`. I know several questions have asked that very question but I'm looking for that specific awful line.

Thanks!!

Comment: I assume that you only set `A`'s property to that of `B` is `B` actually has a value, so you never overwrite a value with null...

Comment: @Sam Holder if I wanted to do that I would probably use ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your properties don't have any logic in their setters, it's unclear why comparing the old vs. new value matters; in the end, your code's logic will ensure that the property values in b are always what's set.

In other words, this would accomplish the same goal:

```
a.Prop1 = b.Prop1;
```

Comment: This does help with doing it for many properties, and although not clear in the question might it be possible that he doesn't want to use null values (or default values?) to overwrite existing values

Answer (score 1):

If you consider this logically for a second:

```
a.Prop1 = a.Prop1 != b.Prop1 : b.Prop1 ? a.Prop1;
```

This will change Prop1 only if it's b's Prop1 is different.

So essentially, in the end you have the value of b.Prop1 anyway.

So, you can just do `a.Prop1 = b.Prop1;`

Answer (score 1):

you could probably do it by writing an method which reflected over A and found each property that had a getter and a setter and then found the same property on B and set the value to Bs value if B is not null and the property in A does not equal the property in B

**EDIT**

as all you want to do is to set `A`'s properties to `B`s then you could just do this to avoid doing it manually:

As blantently cribbed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361187/c-reflection-merge-two-objects-together/3361288#3361288) but updated to do it for every property:

```
   public static TEntity CopyTo<TEntity>(this TEntity OriginalEntity, TEntity NewEntity)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] oProperties = OriginalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo CurrentProperty in oProperties.Where(p => p.CanWrite))
        {
            CurrentProperty.SetValue(OriginalEntity, newEntityValue, null);
        }

        return OriginalEntity;
    }
```

an extension method along these lines should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is smelly.
So if `A` equals `B`...
Then set `A` to `A` (which is `B`)...
else set to `B`.

This is the same as "set `A` to `B`".

So `a.Prop1 = b.Prop1`. is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying and pasting, you could just make a class level method in a called combine that returned a new instance.

```
public A combine(A target)
{
return new A {Prop1 = target.Prop1, Prop2 = this.Prop2 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly but you could probably make use of the null-coalescing operator:

```
public class A {
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int? Prop2 {get;set;}

    public static A Merge(A a, A b) {

        var res = new A();

        //res.Prop = b.Prop unless b.Prop is null, in which case res.Porp = a.Prop
        res.Prop1 = b.Prop1 ?? a.Prop1;
        res.Prop2 = b.Prop2 ?? a.Prop2;

        return res;
    }
}


var a = new A() {Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = 1};
var b = new A() {Prop1 = "B"};
var c = A.Merge(a,b);
```

This way, only the properties that were set in B get copied over to the new class, otherwise the properties from a are the ones chosen.