# Merge data from base class into derived class

Tags: c#

I have a class structure like this:

Spatial --> ServiceRequest --> ServiceRequestSystemX

I have written a method to return a list of ServiceRequestSystemX. The data is held separately to where the Spatial information is stored. So each time I create a new object of type ServiceRequestSystemX I make a call to a different interface to return the Spatial object for that service request.

Now because ServiceRequestSystemX is ultimately derived from Spatial, is there a quick way that I can merge my Spatial object into my ServiceRequestSystemX object without just having to do:

```
ServiceRequestSystemX.X_Coordinate = Spatial.X_Coordinate;
```

which I find tedious and unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a derived type, the ServiceRequestSystemX will already expose base members exposed by the Spatial class.

Comment: I know... what I want to find out is if I already have an object of type ServiceRequestSystemX and I then get a separate object of type Spatial can I quickly merge Spatial into ServiceRequestSystemX somehow?

Comment: I don't think there's a very easy way because you can't implicitly cast types **down** the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in my first answer, you **could** try using reflection to merge the two objects together. But I would call this a dirty hack.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TEntity CopyTo<TEntity>(this TEntity OriginalEntity, TEntity NewEntity)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] oProperties = OriginalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo CurrentProperty in oProperties.Where(p => p.CanWrite))
        {
            if (CurrentProperty.GetValue(NewEntity, null) != null)
            {
                CurrentProperty.SetValue(OriginalEntity, CurrentProperty.GetValue(NewEntity, null), null);
            }
        }

        return OriginalEntity;
    }
}
```

This code taken from another post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361187/c-sharp-reflection-merge-two-objects-together).

Comment: Doesn't seem all that simple, was hoping there might be a quick method call but alas not! Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Once you create the extension above, you could use `MySpatial.CopyTo(MyServiceRequestSystemX)` - but it would only fill properties which are the same on both sides of the merge.