# Merge extended class with the base class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, merge, base-class

I have two classes, one called MemberModel and one called CustomPrincipal. The CustomPrincipal class inheritances the MemberModel class.

The MemberModel class looks like this:

```
namespace example.Models
{
    public class MemberModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool Remember { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The CustomPrincipal class looks like this:

```
namespace example.Examples
{
    public class CustomPrincipal : MemberModel, IPrincipal
    {
        public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
        {
            this.Identity = identity;
        }

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInRole(string role) { return false; }
    }
}
```

In the example below you see two classes MemberModel what is filled with the username, password and remember and the CustomPrincipal class what is filled with the IIDentity information BUT not the username, password and remember.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MemberModel memberModel = serializer.Deserialize<MemberModel>(authTicket.UserData);

IIdentity user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(user);
```

Now I want the attributes from the MemberModel to be merged with the attributes of the CustomPrincipal.

I have tryed multiple things but none of them are working. I tryed to cast the the MemberModel to the CustomPrincipal, but unfortunately this did not work (see below).

```
customPrincipal = (CustomPrincipal) memberModel;
Unable to cast object of type 'example.Examples.Models.MemberModel' to type 'example.Examples.CustomPrincipal'.
```

I have also tryed the example of [Rob Harley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15088515/2798511), that uses reflection to merge the two object, but this also did not work.

Comment: what exactly is the result that you expect to achieve in the end?

Comment: @MongZhu Edited question :)

Comment: I'm afraid the best solution in your case would be to write a method in `CustomPrincipal` that takes `MemberModel` as an argument and sets those properties manually or make a constructor accepting  `MemberModel`

Comment: Instead of a Method you could add a parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have fixed it using reflection on the right way.

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MemberModel).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    if (prop.Name != "Password")
        customPrincipal.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(customPrincipal, serializeModel.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(memberModel, null) as string);
}
```

First we get all the propeties from the MemberModel, then we loop through all these properties and set the value of the customPrincipal by the value of the MemberModel.

Answer (score 5):

The rules of inheritance won't allow you cast a base class (`MemberModel`) into a child class (`CustomPrincipal`). You're only allowed to cast a child class back into a base..

In example,

`(DOG, CAT) => ANIMAL`

I have a dog and a cat and I know that both of them are animals. Therefore, I can treat the dog and the cat as an animal.

`CAT => ANIMAL => DOG`

Let's say the cat is an animal but you want to turn that animal into a dog, you cannot! Why? because you don't really know if it is a dog or not.

Best you can do is add a constructor overload or a method that returns a `CustomPrincipal` from a `MemberModel`.

```
public CustomPrincipal(MemberModel model)
{
    this.Username = model.Username;
    ...
}
```

or

```
public static CustomPrincipal FromMember(MemberModel model)
{
    return new CustomPrincipal()
    {
        Username = model.Username,
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was how to make this automatically, if I add extra attributes to the MemberModel I do not want to add this also to the CustomPrincipal.

Comment: I am not aware of any programming secrets that does things automatically for you. The shortest way is to create a constructor or a converter method.